# Object collections

Tags: php, collections

**Foreword**

In my project, class methods often return data arrays, for example, a list of products.

In this form:

```
$products = [ 
   "product-1" => [...], 
   "product-2" => [...] 
];
```

When working, I began to encounter various errors, the inconvenience of working with an array, etc.

The first thing I did was implement a class, `ProductItem`.

Now everything is easier. I have an array of `ProductItem` objects.

And my method looks like this:

```
// for example
public function getProducts() : array {
    ...
    return [
       new ProductItem(...),
       new ProductItem(...),
    ];
}
```

The return type of the `getProducts` method is an array.
Other developers are not immediately clear what kind of array? Probably, to solve the problem you need to create a collection of `ProductItem` objects.

**Question**

I would like to be able to quickly create collections of different types (the collection does not have to be universal).

Minimum collection requirements: `Iterable` and `Countable`.

After that, I could create my `ProductItemsCollection` class inheriting from an abstract collection. And to have a ready-made collection of objects in which there could be only classes like `getProducts` when trying to cram another object - an exception.

I want to figure out how this is implemented correctly, without third-party libraries, to understand how it works.

Comment: *to create a collection of **getProducts** objects* ? Mb **ProductItem** ? yesterday link didn’t help?

Comment: @splash58, I fixed a typo.
The link was helpful, thanks.
But she doesn’t fit a bit.

Comment: Ok, what is not enough in arrayObject or arrayIterator?

Comment: Get inheritance from ArrayIterator class